# In java/jpa/hibernate not read the database table modified from other external program

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

primarily I apologize for my bad english.

My problem is my program don't read the record of a table modified from a external program.

My scenario is:

1. I use a table in AS400/DB2 
   | TNOTA | TCOEL | TCOMM |
   |  AGG  |  000  |  123  |
    table there is '123' in field of record;
2. start the my program, it execute a infinite while, every 30 seconds call function funTable0f();
3. at first loop, after the execution of funTable0f() the value change from '123' to 'XYZ';
4. update the record with a sql command (non with the my program) sql; update tabel0f set tcomm = 'ABC' where tnota = 'AGG and tcoel = '000';
5. at second loop, at "SECOND breackpoint", the object show me the old value 'XYZ' and not 'ABC';
6. always at second loop, at "THIRD brackpoint", the value in table remain 'ABC' and not update with 'XYZ' (hiberante remember the value is just 'XYZ' and not apply the update?)

seems it work with a copy in memory cache of table0f and not with a real table of my as400 table.

```
AsTabel0fDao asTabel0fDao = new AsTabel0fDaoMng();

public static void main(String[] args){
    AsOasic0f cmd = null;
    Iterator<AsOasic0f> iter_cmd = null;
    while(true){
        // cmdLs = asOasic0fDao.getCmdToDo();
        cmdLs.addAll(asOasic0fDao.getCmdToDo());

        iter_cmd = cmdLs.iterator();
        while(iter_cmd.hasNext()){
            cmd = iter_cmd.next();
            log.info("Comando: " + cmd.toString());
            
            funTable0f();
        }

        try{
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
[...]
private void funTable0f(){
// FIRST breackpoint

    AsTabel0f asTabel0f = asTabel0fDao.getDaTnotaTcoel("AGG", "000");

// SECOND breackpoint

    String tcomm = "XYZ";
    asTabel0f.setTcomm(tcomm);
    if(!(asTabel0fDao.update(asTabel0f))){
        chiudi();
    }

// THIRD brackpoint

}
```

class primary key:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class AsTabel0fPKey implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String tnota;
    private String tcoel;

    public AsTabel0fPKey(){     }

    public AsTabel0fPKey(String tnota, String tcoel){
        super();
        this.tnota = tnota;
        this.tcoel = tcoel;
    }

    // getters & setters

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "AsTabel0fPKey [tnota=" + tnota + ", tcoel=" + tcoel + "]";
    }
}
```

class model table0f:

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import it.cascino.oasi.dbas.model.pkey.AsTabel0fPKey;
    
    @Entity(name="Tabel0f")
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "AsTabel0f.findAllByTnota", query = "SELECT o FROM Tabel0f o WHERE o.id.tnota = :tnota order by o.id.tcoel"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "AsTabel0f.findByTnotaTcoel", query = "SELECT o FROM Tabel0f o WHERE o.id.tnota = :tnota and o.id.tcoel = :tcoel")
    })
    public class AsTabel0f implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        @EmbeddedId
        private AsTabel0fPKey id;
        private String tcomm;
        
        public AsTabel0f(){
            this.id = new AsTabel0fPKey();
        }
        
// getters & setters

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "AsTabel0f [id=" + id + ", tcomm=" + tcomm + "]";
        }
    }
```

persistance:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DB2AS400" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:as400://10.0.21.20/cas_dat;transaction isolation=none" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="JAVAPGM" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="1" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    [...]
    </persistence>
```

entity manager factory:

```
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;
    
    public class Resources{
        private EntityManagerFactory emfAs = null;
        private EntityManager emAs = null;
        private EntityTransaction utxAs = null;
    
        public Resources(){
            super();
            if(emfAs == null) {
                initAs();
            }
        }
        
        private void initAs(){
            emfAs = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DB2AS400");
            emAs = emfAs.createEntityManager();
            utxAs = emAs.getTransaction();
        }
    
        public void close(){
            if(emfAs != null) {
                closeAs();
            }
        }
    
        private void closeAs(){
            emAs.close();
            emfAs.close();
        }
        
        public EntityManagerFactory getEmfAs(){
            return emfAs;
        }
        
        public void setEmfAs(EntityManagerFactory emfAs){
            this.emfAs = emfAs;
        }
        
        public EntityManager getEmAs(){
            return emAs;
        }
        
        public void setEmAs(EntityManager emAs){
            this.emAs = emAs;
        }
        
        public EntityTransaction getUtxAs(){
            return utxAs;
        }
        
        public void setUtxAs(EntityTransaction utxAs){
            this.utxAs = utxAs;
        }
    }
```

DAO:

```
    public interface AsTabel0fDao{
        Boolean update(AsTabel0f o);
    
        AsTabel0f getDaTnotaTcoel(String tnota, String tcoel);
    
        void close();
    }
```

Managment:

```
    public class AsTabel0fDaoMng implements AsTabel0fDao, Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Resources res = new Resources();
        private EntityManager em = res.getEmAs();
        private EntityTransaction utx = res.getUtxAs();
    
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AsTabel0fDaoMng.class);
    
    public Boolean update(AsTabel0f o){
        try{
            try{
                utx.begin();
                log.info("aggiorna: " + o.toString());
                em.merge(o);
            }finally{
                utx.commit();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.fatal(e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public AsTabel0f getDaTnotaTcoel(String tnota, String tcoel){
        AsTabel0f o = null;
        try{
            try{
                utx.begin();
                Query query = em.createNamedQuery("AsTabel0f.findByTnotaTcoel");
                query.setParameter("tnota", tnota);
                query.setParameter("tcoel", tcoel);
                o = (AsTabel0f)query.getSingleResult();
            }catch(NoResultException e){
                o = null;
            }
            utx.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.fatal(e.toString());
        }
        return o;
    }
    
    public void close(){
        res.close();
        log.info("chiuso");
    }
}
```

I hope I was clear,
thanks in advance,
Riccardo

Comment: Do you catch any errors with `log.fatal(e.toString());`?

Comment: First, note that you don't need a transaction to read data from persistence layer, as you do in getDaTNotaTcoel. Second: realize that some JPA impls do cache data on memory. Tha said, check three things: first, remember to commit your pure update SQL commands when executed ouside applications; second, turn on your SQL logs in persistence.xml so you can see if the database is queried by your application properly; last, try to evict() your object prior your queries after the external SQL update.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu not register nothing

Comment: @PauloAraújo as you suggested, I removed from getDaTNotaTcoel() the utx.begin(); and utx.commit();

Comment: @PauloAraújo I add the funtion<br/>`public void evict(Object entity){  em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(entity.getClass());}`, call it after update method, but the problem remain. I have read that evict() manage the second level cache and not the session cache, maybe is for this reason it not work fine?

Comment: Sorry, I've mentioned evict, but my intent was EntityManager#detach function. Please try again using it.

Comment: @PauloAraújo your solution, with detach function, is perfect. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solved with EntityManager#detach as suggested by @PauloAraújo

I post the solution for help some else in the future.

in main class

```
    if(!(asTabel0fDao.update(asTabel0f))){
        chiudi();
    }
    asTabel0fDao.detach(asTabel0f);  // it solve my problem
```

in managment class:

```
    public void detach(Object entity){
        em.detach(entity);
    }
```

Thanks,
Riccardo